# ReSharper Documentation Tags Formatting One Per Line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I'm trying to get ReSharper to behave properly when creating XML comments.

When I see the preview it looks exactly how I want it to look but when I actually document a method or a class it isn't formatting as per the preview.

I get this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The trace.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="level">
    /// The level.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="tag">
    /// The tag.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="message">
    /// The message.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="args">
    /// The args.
    /// </param>
```

When in fact the preview (and what I want) looks like this:

```
    /// <summary> The trace. </summary>
    /// <param name="level"> The level. </param>
    /// <param name="tag"> The tag. </param>
    /// <param name="message"> The message. </param>
    /// <param name="args"> The args. </param>
```

I've tried saving these settings machine wide and as far as I can tell my solution settings match the global settings but still no joy.

How do I get this to function as I want?  (I'm using ReSharper 7.1.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was looking in all the wrong places.  I was attempting to fix the comments layout by using the refactoring settings.  The settings to format the XML comments at creation time are in the StyleCop settings here:

[image]